# How do I split a date?

Tags: datetime

I need to split a date (German format) and store its single elements in variables (to use it in TikZ-calendar).

A German formatted date looks like 23.01.2012 (Day.Month.Year), so I could use the dots as a separation marker.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to start.
Has anyone suggestions or done this before?

Comment: I was going to suggest the `isodate` package, but I don't think it can actually do what you want…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a simple split function you can use a delimited macro. You could simply do this:

```
\def\mysplit#1.#2.#3.{\def\myday{#1}\def\mymonth{#2}\def\myyear{#3}}
\def\splitdate#1{\expandafter\mysplit#1.}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent We have the date: 23.01.2012 \splitdate{23.01.2012}\\
  Day: \myday\\
  Month: \mymonth\\
  Year: \myyear
\end{document}
```

result:

[image: date split in separate variables]

Note that right now this approach lacks any kind of error handling for wrongly formatted output.

**Edit:** Some additional explanation regarding the `\expandafter`.

The difference is the added `\expandafter`. What happens when using `\splitdate{<argument>}` then `\mysplit#1` is replaced by `\mysplit<argument to \splitdate>`. When `<argument to \splitdate>` is not a date formatted like `dd.mm.yyyy` but a macro `\mydate` which is defined as `\def\mydate{10.10.2010}` then `\mysplit\mydate` does not match the definition of `\mysplit` (since that needs arguments delimited by `.`). When we use `\expandafter`, `\mysplit` is left untouched and `\mydate` is expanded first. This leads to `\mysplit10.10.2010`, then `\mysplit` is expanded and the arguments match the definition. When we have an additional layer, like `\def\mydate{12.12.2012}\def\otherdate{\mydate}` then this will still fail since `\expandafter` will only expand the token once. We could make this work as well, by adding a local expanded definition which we use. The complete code would then look like this:

```
\def\mysplit#1.#2.#3.{\gdef\myday{#1}\gdef\mymonth{#2}\gdef\myyear{#3}}
\def\splitdate#1{{\edef\x{#1}\expandafter\mysplit\x.}}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \def\mydate{23.01.2012}
  \def\deepdate{\mydate}
  \noindent We have the date: 23.01.2012 \splitdate{\deepdate}\\
  Day: \myday\\
  Month: \mymonth\\
  Year: \myyear
\end{document}
```

Note that we had to change the definition of `\myday` etc. to global.

Comment: I would at least do `\def\splitdate#1{\expandafter\mysplit#1.}` to have the argument expanded once. This way people can do something like `\splitdate{\mydate}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Agreed, I added it.

Comment: Would you explain the difference please?

Comment: @schmendrich: added some explanation.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `\StrBefore`, `\StrBetween`, and `\StrBehind` from the [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\ExtractDay}[1]{\StrBefore[1]{#1}{.}}%
\newcommand*{\ExtractMonth}[1]{\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{.}{.}}%
\newcommand*{\ExtractYear}[1]{\StrBehind[2]{#1}{.}}%

\newcommand*{\MySplit}[1]{%
    \def\MyDay{\ExtractDay{#1}}%
    \def\MyMonth{\ExtractMonth{#1}}%
    \def\MyYear{\ExtractYear{#1}}%
}%

\begin{document}
  \noindent We have the date: 23.01.2012\\
  Day:   \ExtractDay{23.01.2012}\\
  Month: \ExtractMonth{23.01.2012}\\
  Year:  \ExtractYear{23.01.2012}

  \bigskip
  \noindent If you prefer to have separate macros define for each component

  \noindent We have the date: 23.01.2012 \MySplit{23.01.2012}\\
  Day:   \MyDay\\
  Month: \MyMonth\\
  Year:  \MyYear
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `\year`, `\month` and `\day` to get the different parts of the date. they work as integer registers. so you can use

```
\the\year.\the\month.\the\day
```

to get what you want.

Comment: This refers only to today's date. A calendar usually has more than this.

Comment: Isn't that only for the date today?