# How to extract year from date in iso 8601 format?

Tags: expansion, datatool, xstring, date

I want to extract the year (or day or month) of a date which is stored as ISO 8601 in a database.

My MWE looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{datatool}


\newcommand{\myload}[3][1]{%
  \DTLgetvalue
  {\thevalue}
  {#2}
  {#1}
  {\dtlcolumnindex
    {#2}
    {#3}}%
}

%\get{<DATABASE>}{<FIELD>}
\newcommand{\get}[3][1]{%
  \myload[#1]{#2}{#3}
   \thevalue%
  }


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42027/98739
\newcommand*{\dfgExtractYear}[1]{\StrBefore[1]{#1}{-}}%
\newcommand*{\dfgExtractMonth}[1]{\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{-}{-}}%
\newcommand*{\dfgExtractDay}[1]{\StrBehind[2]{#1}{-}}%


% database

\DTLnewdb{name}
\DTLnewrow{name}
\DTLnewdbentry{name}{dateBirth}{1980-12-04}

\begin{document}

date: \get{name}{dateBirth}\\ % works
Year: \dfgExtractYear{YYYY-MM-DD}\\% works
Day: \dfgExtractDay{YYYY-MM-DD}\\% works
Month: \dfgExtractMonth{YYYY-MM-DD}\\% works


Only Year: \dfgExtractMonth{\get{name}{dateBirth}}% does not work

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

*How can I combine the extraction code of the date-part with the entry of the database?*

Comment: thank you, but i am not able to transfer the solution proposed their onto my code. any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation can be found in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632508/250119, or my answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646000/250119 (case 2.1.1), namely your defined `\get` is not fully expandable.

To fix this particular case, you must move `\myload` outside:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{datatool}


\newcommand{\myload}[3][1]{%
  \DTLgetvalue
  {\thevalue}
  {#2}
  {#1}
  {\dtlcolumnindex
    {#2}
    {#3}}%
}

%\get{<DATABASE>}{<FIELD>}
\newcommand{\get}[3][1]{%
  \myload[#1]{#2}{#3}
   \thevalue%
  }


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42027/98739
\newcommand*{\dfgExtractYear}[1]{\StrBefore[1]{#1}{-}}%
\newcommand*{\dfgExtractMonth}[1]{\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{-}{-}}%
\newcommand*{\dfgExtractDay}[1]{\StrBehind[2]{#1}{-}}%


% database

\DTLnewdb{name}
\DTLnewrow{name}
\DTLnewdbentry{name}{dateBirth}{1980-12-04}

\begin{document}

date: \get{name}{dateBirth}\\ % works
Year: \dfgExtractYear{YYYY-MM-DD}\\% works
Day: \dfgExtractDay{YYYY-MM-DD}\\% works
Month: \dfgExtractMonth{YYYY-MM-DD}\\% works


Only Year: \myload{name}{dateBirth}\dfgExtractMonth{\thevalue}
\end{document}
```

(only the second-last line is changed). It's rather inconvenient.

Alternatively, for a convenient option, use the `functional` package to define both `\get` and `\dfgExtractMonth`, that way you'll be able to use `\get` inside an argument of `\dfgExtractMonth`, but currently it doesn't support optional argument (see [Use \input with siunitx's \num](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645104/250119)  and there are some workarounds)

Comment: Just to make this one answered, as I use this one as an example linked from my answer there.